# Firebase Remote Config does not work in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-remote-config

No matter what I try, it seems like it is not possible to fetch values from the console with firebase remote config.

I am, "connected" but no values are being fetched besides the default values I have set.

I am using react-native-firebase (v6) https://rnfirebase.io/remote-config/usage

```
//Package JSON
"react-native": "0.66.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.1",
"@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^14.11.1",
```

Here is my code which is executed on app load:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const appVersion = DeviceInfo.getVersion();

    await remoteConfig().setConfigSettings({
      minimumFetchIntervalMillis: 30000,
    });

    await remoteConfig()
      .setDefaults({
        is_application_on: true,
        min_app_version: appVersion
      })
      .then(() => remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate())
      .then((fetchedRemotely) => {});

      let isAppOn = remoteConfig().getBoolean('is_application_on');
      let appMinVersion = remoteConfig().getNumber('min_app_version');

      this.setState({
        isAppOn: isAppOn ? true : false
      }, () => {
        alert(this.state.isAppOn)
        alert(appMinVersion)
      })
}
```

My firebase is connected but remote config is the only module I cannot seem to connect to...

Cheers.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this, i m facing same issue, no luck with expo + firebase remote config

Comment: Hey Swati, I was able to fix it. Make sure that you're pointing to the correct google plist file. In my case it was pointing to the wrong one (it was pointing to the dev file from the prod environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it.

Make sure that you're pointing to the correct google plist file.

In my case it was pointing to the wrong one in xcode, my buildphase script code was off.

Comment: were u using Expo too

Comment: I am not using expo